# What C# construct map to PHP arrays?

Tags: c#, php, arrays

I will just list out some arrays and ask how to do them in C#.

```
$myArray = array();
```

In PHP I don't have to declare a memory size for the array. What if I don't know big I need my array?

```
$myArray = array("Name" => "Steve");
```

How do I do the above in C#?

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray['Names'][0] = "Steve";
$myArray['Names'][1] = "Jim";
```

How does the above work in C#"?

Comment: There is a great deal of documentation and tutorials online for C#.  I would consult those resources before asking stackoverflow.

Comment: Look into using generic collections, such as `List<T>` and `Dictionary<T>`.

Comment: Side note: please avoid unrelated text like "I'm new here", "searched a lot", "learning", "thank you", "help me" in posts on SO.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov help me

Comment: You should check out what the standard computer science definition of an array is because the "array" in PHP is very different from that, the array in C# ( `T[]` ) behaves far more like an array in C.

Comment: @David arrays are generic collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$myArray = array("Name" => "Steve");
```

This is a map. PHP doesn't need you to know that, but C# does. You would implement this as:

```
var myArray = new Dictionary<String, String>();
```

For your second case

```
$myArray['Names'][0] = "Steve";
```

This is a dictionary where the keys are Strings, but the values are `String[]`. In C#:

```
var myArray = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
```

Comment: AMAZING! That helps me so so much. I really need that visual tie in! Great community thanks again!

Comment: +1: Note that C# encourages strong typing - Instead of `Dictionary<string, string>` for something like "person with first/last name and title" consider creating type `Person` with corresponding fields. Than use `List<Person>` instead of `List<Dictionary<String, String>>`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov brings up a good point. Moving from PHP (dynamically typed) to C# (statically typed, for the most part) isn't only about learning the syntax, but also a change in your thought process.

Answer (score 2):

arrays in PHP are most like maps or `C# Dictionary` .  An array in PHP is actually what is called an `associative array` .  So for your code above the C# equivalent is:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> items= new Dictionary<string, string>();  
        items.Add("Name", "Steve");
```

if you want a key to point to multiple values:

```
        Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>> items= new  
                           Dictionary<string, ICollection<String>>();    
        ICollection<string> names = new List<string>();  
        names.Add("Steve");     
        items.Add("Name", names);
```

Comment: again, there's a reason the `var` keyword was introduced in C#.

Comment: @HighCore when someone is learning a language it is best to be **explicit** with what you mean.  But yes `var` is very useful.

Comment: agreed, however there are cases (precisely when someone comes from other languages) where the excess of explicitness might be seen by some as "a bloated language syntax"

Comment: I got it! No worries there. Thanks so much!